# Deploying SQL Server Stored Procedure to multiple servers

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

I manage several SQL Servers 2000, 2005 and 2008; I maintain several scripts in the form of stored procedures and functions for may daily activities; as the need arise I do changes to my local copies of those scripts then I need to apply those changes to the same stored procedures and functions on every database server; it's time consuming and painful to connect to every database server and replace what's in there.

I've been trying to use sqlcmd utility with option -i but it's not working well; it keeps erroring out.

Is there a way or a tool that I can use to deploy my local stored procedures and functions to multiple sql servers?

stored procedures and functions have this structure

```
use dba
go

check if stored procedure or function exists 
   if so, drop it

create stored procedure or function
```

Comment: Try [Red-Gate SQL Multi-Script](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-multi-script/)

Comment: BTW, you do know that there should be a `go` just before `create proc/function` in a script like yours, don't you?